# why custom filter reset button is not working for antd filterdropdown in table?

Tags: reactjs, filter, antd

I have this custom filter for date , filter button is working as expected but reset button is not working, can anyone help me,what's wrong here?

Below is my code which contain handlesearch,handlereset functions and all the props that is passed in the columns.So for clearing the filter i am using clearFilters method which we get from filterDropdown. But i am not able to reset the filter.

```
const handleSearch = (selectedKeys, confirm, dataIndex) => {
    console.log(selectedKeys, confirm, dataIndex)
    confirm()
  }

  const handleReset = (clearFilters, dataIndex) => {
    console.log(clearFilters)
    clearFilters()
  }
  const getColumnSearchProps = (dataIndex) => ({
    filterDropdown: ({
      setSelectedKeys,
      selectedKeys,
      confirm,
      clearFilters,
    }) => (
      <div style={{ padding: 8 }}>
        <Form form={form}>
          <DatePicker
            format={'DD-MMM-YYYY'}
            onChange={(e) => {
              setSelectedKeys([e.format('DD-MMM-YYYY')])
            }}
            allowClear={false}
          />

          <Button
            type="primary"
            onClick={() => handleSearch(selectedKeys, confirm, dataIndex)}
            icon={<Filter />}
            htmlType="submit"
            size="small"
            style={{ width: 90 }}
          ></Button>
          <Button
            type="primary"
            onClick={() => handleReset(clearFilters, dataIndex)}
            size="small"
            icon={<Filter />}
            style={{ width: 90 }}
          >
            Reset
          </Button>
        </Form>
      </div>
    ),
    filterIcon: (filtered) => (
      <Filter style={{ color: filtered ? '#1890ff' : undefined }} />
    ),
    onFilter: (value, record) => {
      return moment(record[dataIndex]).format('DD-MMM-YYYY') === value
    },

   
   
  })
```

Comment: Reset button not working as in the click event is not firing or your `clearFilters` function not working as you want it to. If it's the `clearFilters` function then you will need to post the code for that function

Answer (score 0):

Can you try put confirm() in handleReset function.

```
const handleReset = (clearFilters,confirm, dataIndex) => {
      console.log(clearFilters)
      clearFilters()
      confirm()
}
```

This will trigger props onChange in component Table ANTD